# Notepad++ - How can I replace blank lines

Tags: replace, notepad++, blank-line

I have a text file with a thousand lines of numbers like so:

```
402

115

90

...
```

As you can see there is a blank line in between each number that I want to remove so that I have

```
402
115
90
...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That move-to-SU voter, just put [notepad++] in your ignored tags and move on, because [questions about a programmer's text editor are allowed here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 192, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Replace)
2. Select `Extended` from `SearchMode`
3. Put `\r\n\r\n` in `Find What`
4. Put `\r\n` in `ReplaceWith`
5. Click on `Replace All`

[image: Replace multiple line breaks]

Comment: Actually, this only works if there are only two new lines between each line of text.

Comment: @Griffin: The duplicate link I mention beneath the question goes beyond exactly two blank lines.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: It's a plugin that ships with current Notepad++ installations by default. Or at least, as far as I can remember it does...

Comment: In my case, there were several blank lines instead of 2. Repeated click on "Replace All" did the trick.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( the trick edit->line operations->remove empty lines worked perfectly.

Answer (score 169):

As of NP++ V6.2.3 (nor sure about older versions) simply:

1. Go menu -> Edit -> Line operations
2. Choose "Remove Empty Lines" or "Remove Empty Lines (Containing white spaces)" according to your needs.

Comment: I'm trying this, but on a file with about 1.5 million empty rows. The program is just freezing. I'm not sure if it has crashed or just working through all of these rows.

Comment: A bit too late maybe, but for 1.5 million empty rows make a program, I recommend to use Perl a scripting langauge that works very well with text operations.

Answer (score 22):

By the way, in Notepad++ there's built-in plugin that can handle this:
`TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Delete Blank Lines` (first press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all).

Comment: That one works for multiple empty lines too, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This will remove any number of blank lines

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace

Select Extended search mode

replace all `\r\n` with  (space)

then switch to regular expression and replace all `\s+` with `\n`

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro that removes the first blank line, and positions the cursor correctly for the second line. Then you can repeat executing that macro.

Answer (score 1):

This should get your sorted:

- Highlight from the end of the first line, to the very beginning of the third line.
- Use the `Ctrl + H` to bring up the 'Find and Replace' window.
- The highlighed region will already be plased in the 'Find' textbox.
- Replace with: `\r\n`
- 'Replace All' will then remove all the additional line spaces not required.

Here's how it should look:
[image]

Comment: Using NP++ 7.8.1 this is the only solution that works for me. 
I don't understand why I cannot find "\r\n\r\n" used in the many other solutions.