# How to insert blank lines with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Just looking for a way to insert blank lines in every 2 lines in Notepad++, but I cant find the settings for this. Please tell me how to configure this?

Comment: Uhhh... press enter? Not sure what you mean by settings or configuration.

Comment: I don't understand down wotes... very very useful question and wonderful answers.

Answer (score 6):

There is no setting for this thing in notepad++. However the shortcut for:

```
Insert blank line above the current line is: Ctrl+Alt+Enter
Insert blank line below the current line is: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Enter
```

Pressing `Enter` can also insert a new blank line in the case of text files, but in case of script file like python script file pressing Enter generally inserts a new line but with the identations like tabs or spaces, depending upon how you ident your code.

Comment: Although this question is written poorly, and possibly deserving it's low vote, it was the first one to pop up in Google, and this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Find and Replace-> press Ctrl+F

Search mode type : \n

Find what : \n

Replace with : \n\n\n

Select mode : Extended

Comment: sorry meant backslash \n    \n\n

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the cursor on first row.
2. Select command "Start Recording". (Macro->Start Recording)
3. Press **Down arrow button two times** and **End button one time**.
4. Select command "Stop Recording". (Macro->Stop Recording)
5. Select command "Run a Macro multiple times...". (Macro->Run a Macro multiple times...)
6. Select "Run until the end of file" radio button and click "Run" button.
7. Done!

Comment: This is the best answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

put the curser at the first line left most side.(or from where you want to insert new lines)

1. Press ctrl+H
2. Select Regular expression
3. give `\r` in find what
4. give `\n` in replace with
5. click replace all

thats all :-)

Comment: What a brilliant answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't discovered a way that you can insert a blank line specifically after every **2** lines, but you could try doing the reverse of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974407/3733680 where the user was looking for a way to *remove* blank lines.

Alternatively, if you want to change the line-height of your document, increasing the font-size of `Brace highlight style` in the `Style Configurator` will create more space between each line of code. The `Style Configurator` is under `Settings` and you need to be in the `Global Styles` list.